# how to extract data entered on a weekend

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a list of client information entered in the database. I want to pull data only entered on a weekend, I was wondering if there is a way to do that?

So far, this is the query I have, however, it gives me all data entered from June 1 to June 27, when I only want data entered in the weekend. If anyone could please help me modify my query to extract the weekend data, I would really appreciate it

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID, CREATED_DATE 
FROM DBA_CLIENTLIST 
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= TO_DATE('2021-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
AND CREATED_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')-2
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your tables so I'll demonstrate it on Scott's EMP.

```
SQL> select empno, ename, to_char(hiredate, 'dd.mm.yyyy, dy') hiredate
  2  from emp
  3  where to_char(hiredate, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english') in ('sat', 'sun');

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ------------------------
      7521 WARD       22.02.1981, sun
      7934 MILLER     23.01.1982, sat

SQL>
```

So, literally fetch rows whose date values fall into sat(urday) and sun(day).

---

Your query would then be

```
select client_id, created_date
from dba_clientlist
where to_char(created_date, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english') in ('sat', 'sun');
```

Comment: the dates are set up like this: "2021-06-27" so it is difficulty to use the date names such as Sat or Sun to fetch data

Comment: If CREATED_DATE column's datatype is DATE (it **should** be; if it is VARCHAR2, you're doing it wrong), then it just doesn't matter. Format you posted is how your client displays it. TO_CHAR (as I showed you) will properly do the job. I edited the answer and added code you should run.

Answer (score 2):

You may use ISO week as a starting point, which is culture independent:

```
select *
from your_table
where trunc(created_date) - trunc(created_date, 'IW') in (5,6)
```

ISO week starts on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') full_name,  
       to_char(sysdate, 'DY') abbreviation,  
       to_char(sysdate, 'D') day_of_week  
from   dual
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.